# Integrate ArcGIS's timeslider tool to ios swift xcode app

Tags: ios, swift, arcgis

I'm having a problem showing timeslider in my mobile app.

I've installed arcgis-runtime-toolkit and everything seems work just fine but the time slider is not showing.

class MapViewController: UIViewController {

```
private var map = AGSMap(basemap: AGSBasemap.topographic())
private var timeSlider = TimeSlider()



struct EphemeralCacheKeys {
    static let newSpatialFeature = "MapViewController.newFeature.spatial"
    static let newNonSpatialFeature = "MapViewController.newFeature.nonspatial"
    static let newRelatedRecord = "MapViewController.newRelatedRecord"
}

enum MapViewMode: Equatable {
    case defaultView
    case disabled
    case selectedFeature(featureLoaded: Bool)
    case selectingFeature
    case offlineMask
}

weak var delegate: MapViewControllerDelegate?

let changeHandler = AppContextChangeHandler()

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: AGSMapView!
@IBOutlet weak var smallPopupView: ShrinkingView!
@IBOutlet weak var popupsContainerView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var addPopupRelatedRecordButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var selectView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var pinDropView: PinDropView!
weak var activityBarView: ActivityBarView!
@IBOutlet weak var slideNotificationView: SlideNotificationView!
@IBOutlet weak var compassView: CompassView!
@IBOutlet weak var reloadMapButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var relatedRecordHeaderLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var relatedRecordSubheaderLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var relatedRecordsNLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var selectViewTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var selectViewHeaderLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var selectViewSubheaderLabel: UILabel!

var maskViewController: MaskViewController!
@IBOutlet weak var maskViewContainer: UIView!

var featureDetailViewBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

var visibleAreaObserver: NSKeyValueObservation?

var identifyOperation: AGSCancelable?

var mapViewMode: MapViewMode = .defaultView {
    didSet {
        adjustForMapViewMode(from: oldValue, to: mapViewMode)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapView.map = map

    // Configure time slider
    timeSlider.isHidden = true
    timeSlider.labelMode = .ticks
    timeSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MapViewController.timeSliderValueChanged(timeSlider:)), for: .valueChanged)
    view.addSubview(timeSlider)

    //
    // Add constraints to position the slider
    let margin: CGFloat = 10.0
    timeSlider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    timeSlider.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mapView.attributionTopAnchor, constant: -margin).isActive = true
    timeSlider.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: margin).isActive = true
    timeSlider.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -margin).isActive = true

self.timeSlider.initializeTimeProperties(geoView: self.mapView, observeGeoView: true, completion: { [weak self] (error) in

// Make sure self is around
guard let self = self else {
return
}

// If time slider fails to init then
// return with an error.
guard error == nil else {
self.showError(error!)
return
}

// Show the time slider
self.timeSlider.isHidden = false
})




    // Assign the map view touch delegate and other configurations.
    setupMapView()

    // Builds and constrains the activity view to the map view.
    setupActivityBarView()

    // Ensure the map view attribution bar top auto layout constraint is attached to the small pop-up view.
    setupMapViewAttributionBarAutoLayoutConstraints()

    // Set up the small pop-up view.
    setupSmallPopupView()

    // Set initial map view mode.
    adjustForMapViewMode(from: nil, to: mapViewMode)

    // Associate the compass view to the map view.
    compassView.mapView = mapView

    // Begin listening to changes to the app context.
    subscribeToAppContextChanges()

    // Load map from the app context.
    appContext.loadOfflineMobileMapPackageAndSetMapForCurrentWorkMode()

    // Adjust location display for app location authorization status. If location authorized is undetermined, this will prompt the user for authorization.
    adjustForLocationAuthorizationStatus()

    // If device is not reachable upon launch, inform the end-user.
    displayInitialReachabilityMessage()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    refreshCurrentPopup()
}

@IBAction func userRequestsReloadMap(_ sender: Any) {
    loadMapViewMap()
}

@IBAction func userRequestsAddNewRelatedRecord(_ sender: Any) {

    assert(currentPopupManager != nil, "This function should not be reached if a popup is not currently selected.")

    guard let manager = currentPopupManager, let relationships = manager.richPopup.relationships, let relationship = relationships.oneToMany.first else {
        present(simpleAlertMessage: "Unable to add a new related record.")
        return
    }

    let relatedManager: RichPopupManager

    do {
        relatedManager = try manager.buildRichPopupManagerForNewOneToManyRecord(for: relationship)
    }
    catch {
        present(simpleAlertMessage: "Unable to add a new related record. \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }

    SVProgressHUD.show(withStatus: String(format: "Creating new %@.", (relatedManager.title ?? "related record")))

    relationships.load { [weak self] (error) in

        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()

        guard let self = self else { return }

        guard error == nil else {
            self.present(simpleAlertMessage: error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        EphemeralCache.set(object: relatedManager, forKey: EphemeralCacheKeys.newRelatedRecord)

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "modallyPresentRelatedRecordsPopupViewController", sender: nil)
    }
}

// MARK: Current Pop-Up

private(set) var currentPopupManager: RichPopupManager?

func setCurrentPopup(popup: RichPopup) {

    // Clear existing selection
    currentPopupManager?.popup.feature?.featureTable?.featureLayer?.clearSelection()

    // Build new rich popup manager.
    currentPopupManager = RichPopupManager(richPopup: popup)
}

func clearCurrentPopup() {

    // Clear existing selection.
    currentPopupManager?.popup.feature?.featureTable?.featureLayer?.clearSelection()

    // Nullify current popup manager.
    currentPopupManager = nil
}

override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {

    if identifier == "modallyPresentRelatedRecordsPopupViewController" {
        return currentPopupManager != nil
    }

    return true
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let destination = segue.navigationDestination as? RichPopupViewController {

        if let newPopup = EphemeralCache.get(objectForKey: EphemeralCacheKeys.newSpatialFeature) as? RichPopup {
            setCurrentPopup(popup: newPopup)
            destination.popupManager = currentPopupManager!
            destination.setEditing(true, animated: false)
            mapViewMode = .selectedFeature(featureLoaded: false)
        }
        else if let popupManager = EphemeralCache.get(objectForKey: EphemeralCacheKeys.newRelatedRecord) as? RichPopupManager {
            destination.popupManager = popupManager
            destination.setEditing(true, animated: false)
            destination.shouldLoadRichPopupRelatedRecords = false
        }
        else if let currentPopupManager = currentPopupManager {
            destination.popupManager = currentPopupManager
        }
        else {
            assertionFailure("A rich popup view controller should not present if any of the above scenarios are not met.")
        }
    }
    else if let destination = segue.destination as? MaskViewController {
        maskViewController = destination
    }
}

private func displayInitialReachabilityMessage() {

    if !appReachability.isReachable {
        displayReachabilityMessage(isReachable: false)
    }
}

private func displayReachabilityMessage(isReachable reachable: Bool) {
    let connectionMessage = String(format: "Device %@ connection to the network.", (reachable ? "gained" : "lost"))
    slideNotificationView.showLabel(withNotificationMessage: connectionMessage, forDuration: 6.0)
}

func subscribeToAppContextChanges() {

    let currentMapChange: AppContextChange = .currentMap { [weak self] currentMap in

        guard let self = self else { return }

        self.clearCurrentPopup()
        self.mapViewMode = .defaultView
        self.mapView.map = currentMap
        self.loadMapViewMap()
    }

    let locationAuthorizationChange: AppContextChange = .locationAuthorization { [weak self] authorized in
        self?.adjustForLocationAuthorizationStatus()
    }

    let workModeChange: AppContextChange = .workMode { [weak self] workMode in

        guard let self = self else { return }

        let color: UIColor = (workMode == .online) ? .primary : .offline

        self.activityBarView.colors = (color.lighter, color.darker)
        self.slideNotificationView.messageBackgroundColor = (workMode == .online) ? UIColor.primary.lighter : UIColor.offline.darker
        self.slideNotificationView.messageTextColor = .contrasting
    }

    let reachabilityChange: AppContextChange = .reachability { [weak self] reachable in
        self?.displayReachabilityMessage(isReachable: reachable)
    }

    changeHandler.subscribe(toChanges: [currentMapChange, locationAuthorizationChange, workModeChange, reachabilityChange])
```

}
    public func initializeTimeSteps(timeStepCount: Int, fullExtent: AGSTimeExtent, completion: @escaping (Error?)->Void) {
    }

```
@objc func timeSliderValueChanged(timeSlider: TimeSlider) {
    if mapView.timeExtent != timeSlider.currentExtent {
        mapView.timeExtent = timeSlider.currentExtent
    }
```

}
private func showError(_ error: Error) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
    present(alertController, animated: true)
}
}